# Cross distro daemon command?

Tags: centos6, debian-wheezy, init.d, daemon

I'm trying to write a script to launch a daemon on both centos and debian.

This is the current pseudo script:

```
if [ =f "/etc/init.d/functions" ]
  then
    . /etc/unit.d/functions
    alias STARTSTOPDAEMON=daemon
  else
    alias STARTSTOPDAEMON=start-stop-daemon
fi
```

But then I have two different syntax for the alias...

I have found this on pastebin, I was wondering if it could work cross distro or not.

http://pastebin.com/P6bCsK4S

Any advice?

Comment: Both CentOS and Debian use SystemD in their current version ... Also, did you *test* it?

Comment: On CentOS 6 systemd is not used

Comment: Then make it clear which version you are talking about.

Comment: Actually it should just work on every version of them (I mean, not centos 2 maybe), that's why I have not mentioned a specific version.

Comment: They are too different. Write different scripts.